# how to create event dropdownlist in repeater ( selected changed event)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I want to handle dropdownlist event (selectedindexchanged) for reach item in repeater.

I have each row in repeater: (textbox, textbox, dropdownlist)

Based on dropdownlist value, I want to hide and show the two other textboxes

How can I do it?

Comment: Jquery is your answer. change event of dropdown is what you need. But you need to get textboxs from same row where dropdown is. You can easily find jquery code for that.

Comment: The problem with jQuery is that it requires `id`. The `id` attribute is reserved by .net which assigns it automatically, making it hard to get elements.

Comment: You can put a class on dropdown too. Or you can use $('#<%= drp.ClientID %>') in jquery. Problem with server side approach is much bigger than that (postback on every select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep" >
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="drp" runat ="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text ="aa"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="bb"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

And in codebehind:

VB.NET :

```
Protected  Sub drp_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim drp As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
Dim itm As RepeaterItem = CType(drp.Parent, RepeaterItem)

Dim txtA As TextBox = CType(itm.FindControl("txtA"), TextBox)
 If txtA <> Nothing And drp.SelectedValue ="aa" Then
      'txtA.Text = "AAA";
    txtA.Visible = False
 End If  End Sub
```

OR C#:

```
 protected void drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)sender;
    RepeaterItem itm = (RepeaterItem)drp.Parent;

    TextBox txtA = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("txtA");
     if (txtA != null && drp.SelectedValue =="aa")
    {
          //txtA.Text = "AAA";
        txtA.Visible = false;
    }

}
```